# only 1 error message: 1d returned 1 exit status, C++

Tags: c++, exit, status

im trying to compile this, its unfinished but it should still run:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int hI = 1.5;
int gc = 9.8;
int Velocity;
int Angle;
cout << "Please enter the velocity of the ball at the release in m/s";
cin >> Velocity;
cout << "Please enter the angle of the velocity vector at the time of release in degrees";
cin >> Angle;
return 0;
}
```

I get only one error message when i build it: 1d returned 1 exit status, why??
anything helps thank you

Comment: Compiles fine (MSVC14, g++ 5.3.0).

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Answer (score 0):

May be because hI is int and ur assigning it a float, same for gc